Map of Canada from about 1912? Or earlier?

I saw this map in a youtube video that was mainly about the life of a German inventor who relocated to Canada in 1912. That seems to hint that this is how a map of Canada looked at that time. It is unsurprising to me to see that the provinces of Quebec, Ontario, Manitoba, Saskatchewan, and Alberta were not as extensive as they are now. And the terms "North East Territory" and "North West Territory" seem self-explanatory, unless I'm missing something (and my missing something is distinctly possible).
What was the nature of the geographic areas labeled "Assiniboia", "Athabasca", and "Keewatin"?
The fact that part of the United States is labeled "Dakota" rather than distinguishing between states of North Dakota and South Dakota suggests that this may have been before 1889 when the Territory of Dakota became two states, and thus before Saskatchewan and Alberta became provinces in 1905. Would that be correct? Did Alberta and Saskatchewan have the status of territories then?

Please revise the title to ask a clear question (who, what, where, when). The clearer the question, the more likely you are to get an acceptable answer.  Titles that don't ask clear questions are frequently closed as unclear/lacking focus. more information at history.meta. How to write a good question may also be useful.

Google for Assiniboin and you get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assiniboine

It looks like a map in an atlas.  If you have access to an old-fashioned library, you could look at late 19th century English-language atlases and see if map 29 is this map.  More generally, the arrangement of fine print in the lower left and upper right corners might give a hint at the publisher, which should simplify the search. (https://www.davidrumsey.com/ should be of help too, but my browser does not like it, for some reason)

Not "Assiniboin" but Assiniboia = "a regional administrative district of Canada's North-West Territories". The map shows the jurisdictions as of abt 1890 - after Ontario's boundary moved north to James Bay in 1889, and before Keewatin District expanded east to James Bay in 1895. There might be minor changes that would pinpoint the map's date more precisely, There really should be a date on the map itself, but the resolution of the image isn't good enough for me to see it.

It is a version of map 12 in an atlas printed in 1891 in New York by Appleton, "The Library Atlas of Modern Geography".  I suppose your image comes from some other Appleton atlas.  (I viewed it at https://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/detail/RUMSEY~8~1~260823~5523028:Dominion-of-Canada-12?sort=Pub_List_No_InitialSort%2CPub_Date%2CPub_List_No%2CSeries_No&qvq=w4s:/where%2FCanada;q:pub_list_no%3D%220026.000%22;sort:Pub_List_No_InitialSort%2CPub_Date%2CPub_List_No%2CSeries_No;lc:RUMSEY~8~1&mi=0&trs=5 )

What is your question?

@shoover : You see several questions within this posting.

The same map is at https://www.ebay.com/itm/1893-ANTIQUE-MAP-DOMINION-OF-CANADA-VANCOUVER-ISLAND-QUEBEC-ONTARIO-NEWFOUNDLAND-/141845332535 ; similarly blurry.

Wikipedia has a moving gif of the evolution of Canadian provinces over time at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Canada_provinces_evolution_2.gif (though not with all the subdivisions of the NWT in your map)

This map appears to be the same as an ebay offering, where it is described as

A beautiful antique VICTORIAN map on fine quality paper GOOD condition and rescued from a disbound atlas:
BACON'S NEW GENERAL ATLAS of the WORLD
Map produced & printed by: Bacon's Geographical Establishment in 1893

The ebay image is too blury to make out the lettering in the lower left corner. But the "CANADA 29" in the upper right corner matches what in seen in the OP's image.  As does the photographic background image.
The British Library has a copy of  the 1895 Bacon's New General Atlas of the World for schools and families, listing the author as George Washington Bacon (1830--1921). The Rumsey Map Collection has a few maps from
roughly the same time period, marked with "G. W. Bacon & CO. Ltd., 127, STRAND, LONDON", which a straining eye can almost recognize in the lower left corner of the OP's image.
This (CANADA 29) map is a copy of a map with "CANADA 12" in the upper right corner, and an 1891 copyright notice in the lower right corner, apparently identical in cartographic content, but tinted slightly differently, and lacking the line of blurry script at the lower left corner (south of the Vancouver inset).  According to the David Rumsey Map Collection this map appears in

The Library Atlas Of Modern Geography ... New York, D. Appleton And Company 1892.

Other maps from this 1892 atlas are visible on the Rumsey site, and they make it clear the the number 12 is the number of the map of Canada.  Presumably the number 29 in the OP's image (and in the 1893 Bacon atlas) is the number of the map of Canada there.
So an answer to one of the OP's question is: the map in question was printed in 1893 but is a reprint of a map with an 1891 date. (Which itself might be a reprint of a somewhat earlier map.)

This is the answer to ONE of the questions. Do you know anything about the other one, set in bold?
